# Search for words like in chrome

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox, scrollview

this is how Chrome finds you a word when you search for it:

1) select it in all the places it appears.
2) draw little line in the scroll bar wherever it found the searched word.

[image]

I have a canvas with scroll view around it, and I want to perform the same thing on it.
I gues that for enabling the selection i'll have to use only richtextboxes ?!? (hope not).

any third party or idea or anything will be highly appreciated

Comment: The Chromium Project is open source...

Answer (score 0):

Without looking directly at the Chormium Project (which is open source and available at [Chormium Homepage](http://Chromium.org)) I would imaging what is happening on this particular example is something following these steps:

Word Highlighting

- Search the page source/content for the keyword using a simple regex
- Insert that text into some form of a HTML container (either a span or a div) with a particular id
- Use CSS to style that container to indicated the highlighting

Sidebar Highlighting

- Use some algorithmic method to vertical position of the highlighted term
- Add a indicator to the side bar in a some presentation layer/control that is transparent and below the scroll bar

It may be possible that there exists a 3rd party control that does these things, or it may be possible to leverage your work off of the existing work in the chromium project. However it is most likely not done using a RichTextBoxes nor simple text selection.